# Referencing parent Maven project's files from sub Maven project's pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I have this file structure in my project:

> Parent-project
>   |--pom.xml
>   |--Sub-Project
>   |----pom.xml
>   |----src/
>   |------main/
>   |--------java/
>   |----------*packages and classes*
>   |--WebFolder/
>   |----front/
>   |------*html pages and JS files*

From the Sub-Project's pom.xml, I'd like to include WebFolder as a resource. I want to create a JAR-file using the Sub-Project's pom.xml and I want it to include the WebFolder.

The Sub-Project has a http-server that needs to host the WebFolder. From Sub-Project, I can easily reference the path as **WebFolder/front** to make it point at the web page I want to display, but it needs to be included in the JAR-file as well.

The problem I have is with Maven. From what I've seen, I should be able to create what I want with resources from Sub-Project's pom.xml like so:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>???/WebFolder/</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

The problem is, I don't know how reference something outside the Sub-Project. The directory-tag only seems to reference files inside the Sub-Project. Is there a way to make the directory point at WebFolder?

I'm already using maven-assembly-plugin to include all dependencies in a single JAR-file, but since the WebFolder is not related to Maven per-se, I need to include it with other means.

Comment: Why do you need the WebFolder also in a jar?

Comment: The actual project is a lot more complex than this, but I'm also going to integrate grunt tasks in the website. The idea is that I can easily package everything neatly in one single JAR-file.

Comment: Look into EAR files then.

Answer (score 0):

Maven files & directories are relative to the directory of your pom.xml.
In your example, pom.xml of the sub-project can reference its sibling WebFolder directory as: `<directory>../WebFolder</directory>`

On some cases relative references won't work. On such cases, you could access the project direcory via `${basedir}`